# ipmitool change bios product id on hp dl160 gen8

Tags: hp, ipmitool

I got quite a few HP DL160 Gen8's that I need to change the product ID for since they've received new system boards due to a manufacturing fault and we're trying to keep track of which boards went through which revision (we have 3 different revisions) and they way we decided to keep track of that is through the Product ID on the boards. We utilize ipmitool to retrieve this information, but no one (to my knowledge) in our company knows how do change the product id with it. Anyone here know how? I did a bit of googling before-hand and only found how to setup SOL and a few other commands to retrieve information, identify the system, change power states, etc.

Comment: HPE have an internal tool for doing that, it sounds like it's their fault, get them to send it to you rather than 'rolling your own', it's really easy to use if I recall.

Comment: I've talked with one our reps and they said to use iLo to make the adjustments. But with how we have iLo setup, it's quite a hassle to move around as it's slow and takes several steps to get to it in the first place. Not sure if that's what you're talking about or not.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to set the Product ID and Serial Number on a Gen8 server without going through RBSU(F9) manually is to use Conrep.

You will need the 32-bit Linux version of Conrep to do it.  It is not supported on Windows or 64-bit Linux.

Here is how to change the product ID using conrep:

1. Create a file called conrep.dat that contains the following(enter the serial number and product id here):

   ```
   <Conrep>
   <ProductId>123456-B21</ProductId>
   </Conrep>
   ```
2. Apply the file using conrep:

   ```
    ./conrep –l –f conrep.dat
   ```

Note: put the correct path to all the files in the paths above.

Since you need to use the 32-bit Linux version of Conrep, the easiest way is to download an older version of the Linux Scripting Toolkit that contains the 32-bit version of Conrep and Linux OS.

Here is the link: https://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_6e7f313a13f844028032c1ea95

You can build an ISO image or USB key to boot into Linux and run Conrep.

Another way to do this is via the IPMI tool:

Get product id:

```
Ipmitool 0x36 2 0x0f <count lsb> <count msb>
```

Example:

```
 Ipmitool raw 0x36 2 0x0f 0x10 0
```

Set product id:

```
Ipmitool 0x36 2 0x0e <count lsb> <count msb>  <data 1> <data 2> ….<data n>
```

Where `n = count`

Example:

```
Ipmitool raw 0x36 2 0x0e 9 0 0x50 0x72 0x6F 0x64 0x75 0x63 0x74 0x69 0x64
```

This information was provided by HPE sources.

-Veena

A HPE Employee

Comment: Wow that's pretty detailed, mind if I ask where I could find the HPE sources you used? or did you have a an HP rep you could ask?

Comment: I am a HPE employee for HPE servers, and I was able to receive some help from the engineers who work with IPMItools and conrep.

Comment: Whoops... would have been nice to read you last line huh? Thanks for your help! But I'm having a bit trouble figuring out where to put what to get the ID changed.